# How to sort NSMutableArray of object in ascending and how can I change DateFormat in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am new for **iOS** and I am integrating my app with services

and form services  I am getting "Date" values and I am storing that Date values  in `**NSMutableArray**` so how can I keep in at Ascending order my array list please see below

And how can I change below array list date format like "17 Feb 2016 20:25"  please help me some one

### my array:

```
(
    "02/17/2016 1415",
    "02/13/2016 1415",
    "02/14/2016 1415",
    "02/18/2016 1534",
    "02/21/2016 1534",
    "02/22/2016 1534",
    "02/18/2016 1534",
    "02/20/2016 1534",
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code for sort NsmutableArray in ascending order :

```
NSMutableArray *arr = @[@"02/17/2016",
                        @"02/13/2016",
                        @"02/14/2016",
                        @"02/18/2016",
                        @"02/21/2016",
                        @"02/22/2016",
                        @"02/18/2016",
                        @"02/20/2016"].mutableCopy;

NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
NSArray *arr1 =  [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

and Output :

```
(
"02/13/2016",
"02/14/2016",
"02/17/2016",
"02/18/2016",
"02/18/2016",
"02/20/2016",
"02/21/2016",
"02/22/2016"
)
```

code for change date Formate:

```
 NSString *dateString = @"11-13-2015";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

 // Convert date object into desired format
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
 NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: thanks for answer and i want to change date for mate like "17 Feb 2016"

Comment: how can i change this 01/23/2016 1830 military time formate as like regular time formate bro –

Comment: what is 1830? is it timezone ?

Answer (score 1):

**Sort**

```
 NSSortDescriptor* OrderBy = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES]; // for ascending use `YES`, for Descending USE `NO`
NSArray *finalArar =  [yourmutableArrayName sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: OrderBy]];
```

**Change dateFormat**

```
    for (NSString *dte in finalArar)
    {
     NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

     //your Date String is  02/17/2016
    [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    // for example like this 
    [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
   // or use this [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *parsed = [format dateFromString:dte];
     //final   String is     02 Feb 2016
     [format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
       NSString *newDateString = [format stringFromDate:parsed];
       NSLog(@"final date==%@",newDateString)
      }
```

Comment: hello brother how can i change this 01/23/2016 1830 militory time formate as like regular time formate bro

Comment: set your timexone like `formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];` or  `[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];`

Comment: how can i insert that time zone formate including with date in for loop bro please update ur code

Comment: no bro null values ptinting in NSLog(@"final date==%@",newDateString)

Comment: `[format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];` this is error ,with out this it will work fine. It mean can you update your question where u need ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103811/discussion-between-abhiram-and-anbu-karthik).